# Why does my normal map become invisible when behind a raytraced glass material when rendering with Blender Render (2.49b)

Tags: rendering, texturing

I'm making a wristwatch, I've got a normal map texture on the dial. When I put my glass front on, the normal map doesn't show through. I've enabled transparent shadows, and everything I can think of. If I move the glass to the side so it's half on half off, I can see that underneath, the normal map is rendering correctly. If I change the normal map so it maps to colour, this will render through the glass correctly, but it won't just as a normal map. Help!

---

I should mention that it is in Blender 2.49b :) I prefer it. I just tried the scene in 2.63 and it shows through. So it works in 2.63 (and I assume other post 2.49 versions too). However, why is this? Shouldn't the blender render be the same?? It seems quite a limitation. Surely in the days when 2.49b was king, users attempted to put glass in front of a normal map? There must be a way? If not I will just have to work in 2.49b and render in later versions.

Comment: There is nothing called "raytransp glass" in Blender as far as I am aware of. Please clarify what you mean. It would also help if you added some pictures of your problem, material settings or nodes. What renderer are you using?

Comment: I mean that my glass material for the glass on the front of my wristwatch is set so that "raytracing for transparent refraction rendering" is enabled...I'm using blender render. Not cycles.

Comment: Have you tried adding thickness to the glass?

Comment: Yes. It's the same result with or without thickness.

Comment: I think using 2.49 version is a huge limitation in itself. In fact it is a much bigger limitation then this one feature not working. You are missing a decade of progress! There is absolutely no reason to do that. You cannot possibly benefit from it. 10 years... I think it's time. Just click here: https://www.blender.org/download/

Comment: I do have a later version. 2.63, I will get the latest one too, I just find the modelling workflow much faster in 2.49b, also I'm a stickler for using quads only. Quads can be converted to triangles easily, but not the other way round. I wouldn't like to inadvertently create ngons, which is apparently quite easy to do with post 2.49 versions.